# PyQT QAction/QMenu color

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to find a way to set the items of a menu different colours.

[image: Menu Items]

So, for example, Web Guide is blue, Email Support is red, Version 1.0 is transparent.

I had a look for a while on how to do this, and tried out a Qlabel and QWidgetAction, but that seemed to just act as text, and not in the same way as an action.

I have a feeling that this is more pain then it's worth, but thought i'd throw it out there all the same.

This is how I have the style sheet and actions set up:

```
    self.setStyleSheet("""
        QMenuBar {
            background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border: 1px solid ;
        }

        QMenuBar::item {
            background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
        }

        QMenuBar::item::selected {
            background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
        }

        QMenu {
            background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border: 1px solid ;
        }

        QMenu::item::selected {
            background-color: rgb(30,30,30);

        }
    """)

    self.XactionHelpFAQ = QtGui.QAction('Web Guide', self)
    self.XactionHelpEmail = QtGui.QAction('Email Support', self)
    self.XactionHelpVersion = QtGui.QAction('Version 1.0', self)

    self.Xmenubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
    self.Xmenubar.setObjectName('menubar')
    self.Xmenubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 684, 21))
    self.Xmenubar.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.Xmenubar.setDefaultUp(False)

    self.XmenuHelp = QtGui.QMenu('Help', self.Xmenubar)
    self.XmenuHelp.addAction(self.XactionHelpFAQ)
    self.XmenuHelp.addAction(self.XactionHelpEmail)
    self.XmenuHelp.addAction(self.XactionHelpVersion)
```

Comment: according to your code, you are applying stylesheet to a Widget that contains your MenuBar and Menu but not to the `self.Xmenubar` and `self.XmenuHelp` object. Try to wirte `self.Xmenubar.self.setStyleSheet(...)` and `self.XmenuHelp.setStyleSheet(...)`. To improve your code, you can simply set the whole stylesheet to your `QApplication` object so you can be sure that your stylesheet is applied to all Qt objects.

Comment: Good call, now my second window doesn't have the same menubar style sheet :)
Thanks, it's real fiddly this Ui stuff.

Comment: yes it is, I confirm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a stylesheet, you need to apply it on the widget you are 'styling'.

```
self.Xmenubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
[...]
self.Xmenubar.setStyleSheet("""
    QMenuBar {
        background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid ;
    }

    QMenuBar::item {
        background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }

    QMenuBar::item::selected {
        background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
    }
""")

self.XmenuHelp = QtGui.QMenu('Help', self.Xmenubar)
[...]
self.XmenuHelp.setStyleSheet("""
    QMenu {
        background-color: rgb(49,49,49);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid ;
    }

    QMenu::item::selected {
        background-color: rgb(30,30,30);

    }
""")
```

In most cases, you simply need to apply the general stylesheet to the `QApplication` object and apply some specific stylesheet to Qt object that will override the stylesheet applied to `QApplication`

Comment: Thanks! That's made everything under the Help bar a different colour. I was looking to get some of the items different shades, but think it's probably too much of a faff. This'll do nicely!

Comment: No problem ! I suggest you to open a new question showing a screenshot of what you need and we can try to help you :) We learn from questions and answers.

Comment: @AdamSirrelle Could you please provide the code that worked for you?

Comment: This is from 5 years ago, so this code might not be the best, but it seems I did what syedelec suggested. Although, rather than setting the stylesheet of the one widget, I did one setStyleSheet on the entire widget after it was called. This might not be the best approach, as stylesheets affect all widget children of the widget it was set on. You can get around that by specifying names with #, but in any case the next comment will be what I used. I hope it helps!

Comment: `app.setStyleSheet("""QMenuBar {background-color: rgb(49,49,49); color: rgb(255,255,255); border: 1px solid ;}
        QMenuBar::item {background-color: rgb(49,49,49); color: rgb(255,255,255);}
        QMenuBar::item::selected {background-color: rgb(30,30,30);}
        QMenu {background-color: rgb(49,49,49); color: rgb(255,255,255); border: 1px solid ;}
        QMenu::item::selected {background-color: rgb(30,30,30);}""")`